# How to find a basis for a plane perpendicular to a given vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a vector in R3 and I am being asked to find a basis for a plane in R3.  I am not sure how to go about doing this.  I think it is the formatting of the question that is confusing me.  If someone could help me rephrase this question into other terms I might understand (such as orthogonal, orthonormal, linearly independent, span, etc.), that would be very helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Find two vectors perpendicular to the given vector that are not multiples of each other

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to find a basis for a plane that is perpendicular to a given vector, $v$.

Just solve the linear system $v^Tx=0$ and find a basis for the nullspace of $v^T$.